# Where i can write about response field - .ok?

Tags: python, aiohttp

Any response have a field **.ok**, for example in code:

```py
async with ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.get(url=url) as response:
        if response.ok:
             ...
```

My question is **reponse.status == 200** equal **response.ok**?

And for example if status=204, then reponse.ok is False?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.ok):

> property `ok`
>
> > Returns True if `status_code` is less than 400, False if not.
> >
> > This attribute checks if the status code of the response is between
> > 400 and 600 to see if there was a client error or a server error. If
> > the status code is between 200 and 400, this will return True. This is
> > not a check to see if the response code is `200 OK`.

So with `response.status = 204` it will still be `True`